# Automatic date change in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have recently amended a query i run each week:

**New Query**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`, 
       `lang`, DATE(NOW()) as `week_ending` 
  FROM mytable.data 
 WHERE `date` > "2014-01-13" 
   AND `date` < "2014-01-20" 
 GROUP BY `lang`;
```

**Old Query with previous date example**

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`, 
       `region`, DATE(NOW()) as `week_ending` 
   FROM mytable.data 
  WHERE `date` > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 WEEK) 
    AND `date` < DATE(NOW()) 
  GROUP BY `region`, DATE(NOW());
```

As you can see i had automatically set the query dates to change per week, however with the new query, it is not giving me the correct results as previously? Is there any other way i can have the dates change per week so i can try that method?

Comment: I'm formatting the query for readability. This is always a good idea when troubleshooting.

Comment: What's the type of `date`?  If it's only a "date" (as the input parameters suggest), you're only selecting six days out of the week.  If it's a timestamp, you're selecting _almost_ 7 days - you're missing the start of the first day.  Read [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) about dealing with date/time ranges (yes, it applies to MySQL too).

Answer (score 2):

difference between old and new is old query use current date - 7 days means 2014-01-10 and 2014-01-17...

as i see you are using different group by clause

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`, `lang`, DATE(NOW()) as `week_ending` 
FROM mytable.data 
WHERE `date` > "2014-01-10" 
AND `date` < "2014-01-17" GROUP BY `lang`;
```

Comment: Yes, i have changed the dates in the first query to that of what they would be in the old query -7days (2014-01-10 and 2014-01-17) like you said and i get the same results as the old query so that must mean there is not the required data there for it to output, i have recently made changes to the table so this would be why. I will most likely have to allow my table to populate for over 7 days, then run the query again?!  Thanks :)